# Why is this test giving 0% coverage?

Tags: apex, unit-test, lead-conversion

I have a simple trigger that I'm trying to deploy, but am getting a 0% code coverage error when validating. I had to modify the test slightly to get around another problem (changed "static testMethod void" to "public static void") -- and I'm not sure if that's why the coverage isn't functioning properly or not. Here's my code:

Trigger:

```
trigger updateContactAfterConverted on Lead (after update) {

    for(Lead lead:System.Trigger.new) {

        // was the lead converted?

        if (Lead.IsConverted) {

            // query new contact

            Contact newContact = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Contact.Id = :lead.ConvertedContactId];

            // run @future class to update contact after conversion completed

            updateContactAfterConvertedFuture.myMethod(newContact.id);

        }

    }

}
```

Class called in trigger:

```
public class updateContactAfterConvertedFuture {

  @future 
  public static void myMethod(String newContact) {

    // Find new contact

    Contact updateContact = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Contact.Id = :newContact LIMIT 1];

    // Set field to true                                    

    updateContact.Conversion_Completed__c = TRUE;

    // Update contact               

    update updateContact;     

   }

}
```

Test:

```
@isTest
public class testUpdateContactAfterConvertedOrig {

    public static void myUnitTest() {

            // Create new test lead
            Lead myLead = new Lead(LastName = 'Fry', Company='Fry And Sons', LeadSource = 'Advertising', Lead_Source_Detail__c = 'PPC');
            insert myLead;

            // Convert test lead
            Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
            lc.setLeadId(myLead.id);

            // Check conversion
            LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
            lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);

            // Declare successful
            Test.startTest(); 
            Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
            Test.stopTest();
            System.assert(lcr.isSuccess());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's exactly why. Only methods that are either @isTest methods, or flagged with testMethod, will be executed. So, either of these should work:

```
@isTest static void myUnitTest() { ...
static testMethod void myUnitTest() { ...
```

Please note that the *order* of the keywords is vitally important for compiling properly. Also, your methods may be *private*, which in the code above, is demonstrated by omitting the access modifier keyword.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why the order is important? I think `static void testMethod myUnitTest` will also work?

Comment: @AdrianLarson That won't compile. testMethod must come before the return type.

Comment: So when I use the testMethod keyword, or the @isTest in front of static void, I get 100% code coverage, but I get this error: "Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts Stack Trace: null" That's why I removed it to try and get around the error. I've tried mocking a Web Service callout and an HTTP callout and nothing works.

Comment: You'll probably want to ask that as a separate question/review existing questions. There is definitely a way to mock callouts and web service calls, but they are two separate things. Make sure you're using the right one.

Comment: Got it. I have another question open here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/110170/methods-defined-as-testmethod-do-not-support-web-service-callouts-tried-other-p but haven't had luck there either. I've tried mocking both callouts and web service calls to no avail.