# Help testing a web service callout for a trigger that doesn't directly request a callout

Tags: unit-test, webservices, callout, webservicemock

I'm attempting to include a mock web service callout in a test for a trigger, though the trigger and test don't explicitly execute a callout. I've found [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex_testing.htm) on creating the mock, but I'm pretty new to Apex and am unsure how to configure the two classes: WebServiceMockImpl and WebSvcCallout.

Any guidance would be appreciated. Below is the trigger, an associated class and the current test class.

Trigger:

```
trigger updateContactAfterConverted on Lead (after update) {

    for(Lead lead:System.Trigger.new) {

        // was the lead converted?

        if (Lead.IsConverted) {

            // query new contact

            Contact newContact = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Contact.Id = :lead.ConvertedContactId];

            // run @future class to update contact after conversion completed

            updateContactAfterConvertedFuture.myMethod(newContact.id);

        }

    }

}
```

Associated class:

```
public class updateContactAfterConvertedFuture {

  @future 
  public static void myMethod(String newContact) {

    // Find new contact

    Contact updateContact = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Contact.Id = :newContact LIMIT 1];

    // Set field to true                                    

    updateContact.Conversion_Completed__c = TRUE;

    // Update contact                

    update updateContact;     

   }

}
```

Test class:

```
@isTest
private class testUpdateContactAfterConvertedOrig {

    static testmethod void myUnitTest() {

            Test.startTest();

    // This causes a fake response to be generated
    Test.setMock(WebServiceMock.class, new WebServiceMockImpl());

    // Call the method that invokes a callout
    String output = WebSvcCallout.callEchoString('Hello World!');

    // Verify that a fake result is returned
    System.assertEquals('Mock response', output);                 

            // Create new test lead
            Lead myLead = new Lead(LastName = 'Fry', Company='Fry And Sons', LeadSource = 'Advertising', Lead_Source_Detail__c = 'PPC');
            insert myLead;

            // Convert test lead
            Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
            lc.setLeadId(myLead.id);

            // Check conversion
            LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
            lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);
            lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(True);

            // Declare successful
            Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
            Test.stopTest();
            System.assert(lcr.isSuccess());

    }
}
```

Comment: So what is not working.

Comment: You have configured `WebServiceMockImpl` correctly by registering the mock you want to use. The `WebSvcCallout` code is just an example of code that calls the web service. Can you confirm that you have added code that calls your web service somewhere? A common problem with this sort of test is "System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out" - update your question if you are getting that.

Comment: Sorry -- what's not working is that when I try to deploy my trigger to production (without the callout mock), I get this error: "Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts" -- which I believe means that existing code already deployed in production is making a callout during the lead conversion process. So I wanted to implement the mock to satisfy the requirements of the test. I don't need to make a callout in my trigger itself.

Comment: Related question with the problem: [Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/110170/102)